# How to remove Youku advertise?

Tags: video, ads

I try to remove advertisement from Youku video. Could anybody help me? Do we have any option to control that?
 **js:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://player.youku.com/jsapi"</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 player = new YKU.Player('youkuplayer', {
    styleid: '1',
    client_id: 'CLIENT_ID',
    autoplay: true,
    show_related: false,
    vid: ' XMjg5Njk2NTAzNg==',
    newPlayer: true,
    events: {
        onPlayerReady: function() {
            console.info('player is ready');
        },
        onPlayStart: function() {
            console.info('player started');
        },
        onPlayEnd: function() {
            console.info('player ended');
        }
    }
});
```

And this is my content

**html**

```
<div id="youkuplayer" style="width:480px;height:400px"></div>
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Same problem here. I was able to hide related video, but not the ads that show while playing the video. Any solutions?

Comment: Isn't there a premium option to remove adverts from your videos?